# Why isn't my code drawing everything to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to code a snake game in Javascript, but I can't figure out why the snake and food aren't being drawn. The score is being drawn, but it's the wrong color. I have tried to debug it with developer tools, and everything appears to have the correct values, but it just doesn't show up.

The full code can be found here https://codepen.io/JKrew/pen/KogGxz.

These are my draw functions, the first is in my Snake function, and the second is in my Stage function. I made sure that I call them in my loop.

```
this.draw = function() {
        context.fillStyle = this.color;

        for (let i = this.tail.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            context.fillRect = (this.tail[i].x * cellSize, this.tail[i].y * cellSize, cellSize - 1, cellSize - 1);
        }
    };

this.draw = function() {
            context.fillStyle = this.food.color;
            context.fillRect = (this.food.x * cellSize, this.food.y * cellSize, cellSize - 1, cellSize - 1);

            context.fillSyle = '#FFF';
            context.fillText('Score: ' + snake.tail.length, 5, canvas.height - 5);
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning to the `fillRect` function, rather than just calling it:

```
            context.fillRect = (this.tail[i].x * cellSize, this.tail[i].y * cellSize, cellSize - 1, cellSize - 1);
```

should be

```
            context.fillRect(this.tail[i].x * cellSize, this.tail[i].y * cellSize, cellSize - 1, cellSize - 1);
```

and similar in the second call.

Edit: and the reason this is syntactically valid JavaScript is the rarely-used [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: Thanks so much, I probably never would have caught that.